# Prove that $V \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$ (set of polynomials of degree at most n) is not a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces

> Let $V\subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the set of all polynomials of degree at most $n$, with $n \ge 1.$
>
> Prove that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ and that V is not a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Proving that $V$ is a vector space is easy.

However, I came across some trouble when trying to show that $V$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. Now, from what I know, $V$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ if and only if:

$0 \in V$

if $a,b \in V$ then $a+b\in V$ and $a\cdot b \in V$

if $a \in V$ then $-a \in V$

However, these all hold in $V$. I am not really sure how we are supposed to prove that $V$ is not a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: When you multiply two polynomials of degree at most $n$, the result is not always of degree at most $n$.

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to the second axiom. So, even if $a,b \in V$, it doesn't necessarily guarantee that $a\cdot b \in V$?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Why are you ansswering in a comment?

Comment: We do not. This does make sense, thank you for your help.

Comment: Depending on the convention you are using for rings, i.e. if you mean rings with $1$, you may also want subrings to contain $1$.